# How to refactor uploadArchives for some subprojects at root build.gradle?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a multi project, and I want to upload some of the subprojects artifact to the maven repository.
For now, I wrote the following code into the main build.gradle:

```
task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) { ... }

project(':subProjName1') {
   apply plugin: 'java'
   apply plugin: 'maven'

   configurations {
       subProjName1Archives
   }

   uploadSubProjName1Archives {
       repositories {
           mavenDeployer {
               repository(url: "file:///$rootDir/mvn-repo/")
           }
       }
   }

   artifacts {
       subProjName1Archives jar
       subProjName1Archives sourcesJar
   }
}

project(':subProjName2') { ... }
...
project(':subProjNameN') { ... }
```

And do following for upload archives:

```
gradlew.bat uploadSubProjName1Archives
gradlew.bat uploadSubProjName2Archives
...
gradlew.bat uploadSubProjNameNArchives
```

It's doing what I want, but how can I generalize it into one task in the main build.gradle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put the above code into a `subprojects { .. }` block in the root build script, you can invoke all tasks at once with `gradle uploadMyConfiguration`. (Only) if you have a concrete need for a single task (e.g. because another task depends on all artifacts being uploaded), you can add a further lifecycle task:

```
task uploadAll {
    dependsOn { subprojects.uploadMyConfiguration }
}
```

PS: Unless you have a good reason not to, you can reuse the existing `archives` configuration and `uploadArchives` task. The `archives` configuration already contains the Jar produced by the `jar` task, so you just have to add the `sources` Jar.